# I am having error just after restarting computer in flutter Error: A file can't be part of more than one library

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, pubspec.yaml

I am having this problem since restart and i think due to auto-update package but now i am having this error. This happens when i run my code and stop before executing anything.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Edge in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/firebase_core.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/firebase_core.dart%20: Context: Used as a part in this library.

/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/src/firebase.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/firebase_core.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.3.0/lib/firebase_core.dart%20: Context: Used as a part in this library.

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have tried pub get, Flutter clean, flutter upgrade downgrade. Help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Try `flutter pub cache repair` as well.

Comment: I have tried not working, what would be the reason of this error?